# Родительская директория

Tags: python

Например:

```
mypath = "C:\\some_folder\\some_subfolder"
```

Как получить родительскую директорию по данному пути?
Можно, конечно

```
parent = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(mypath, '..'))
```

но мне этот способ кажется каким-то корявым, как и

```
parent = os.sep.join(os.path.split(mypath)[:-1])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Результат [`os.path.dirname()`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) зависит от наличия слэша в конце пути:

```
>>> os.path.dirname('/a/b')
'/a'
>>> os.path.dirname('/a/b/')
'/a/b'
```

Если это не желательно, то можно использовать [ответ @kender на вопрос "How do I get the parent directory in Python?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2860193/4279):

```
>>> parent_dir = lambda path: os.path.abspath(os.path.join(path, os.pardir))
>>> parent_dir('/a/b')
'/a'
>>> parent_dir('/a/b/')
'/a'
```

[`pathlib.Path.parent`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parent) атрибут ведёт себя похоже:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path('/a/b').parent
PosixPath('/a')
>>> Path('/a/b/').parent
PosixPath('/a')
```

Если в пути могут быть символические ссылки или уже присутствовать `'..'` ([`os.pardir`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.pardir)), то в зависимости от желаемого  результата может потребоваться ещё [`os.path.realpath(path_with_symlink)`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath), [`os.path.abspath(path_with_dots)`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) или  [`pathlib.Path.resolve()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve) вызвать.

Comment: Пожалуй, `os.path.abspath(os.path.join(path, os.pardir))` мне нравится больше. Кстати, с `..` в пути он справляется отлично. Попутно вопрос, почему `os.listdir(path)` не выдает `..` (в Виндах по крайней мере)?

Comment: @andy.37 С `..` в пути справляется `normpath()`  функция, вызываемая `abspath()`. Про `listdir()` и `'..'` лучше отдельный вопрос задать (я предполагаю `'.'`, и `'..'` не показаны, потому что они в каждой директории есть и означают всегда одно и то же как правило).

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать `os.path.dirname('path')`. Если нужна директория еще ниже, передаете полученное значение дальше.
Вот, к примеру, настройки из Django проекта

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

>>> BASE_DIR
'/home/user/projects/myproject'
>>> os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
'/home/user/projects'
```

Comment: Спасибо. Как то я не нашел очевидного)) Как раз с django ковыряюсь, понадобилось, а `listdir` `..` не выдает.

Comment: @andy.37 пожалуйста

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/  scandir(path='.') -> generator of DirEntry objects